# file input ref triggering file-picker twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

File input ref is triggering twice when I click button multiple times very quickly -

```
<input
    type="file"
    ref={uploadRef}
    ...
/>
<DefaultButton
    onClick={onClick}
    ...
/>
```

and,

```
const onClick = React.useCallback(
    (e) => {
        uploadRef.current?.click();
        // e.stopPropagation();
        }
    },
    []
```

Related info - I tried `e.stopPropagation()` mentioned here - https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/494. This doesn't work.

The Button onclick multiple times "quickly" loads two file pickers in sequence. If I close first, immediately I see next one and the last selection persists.

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); should be used before `uploadRef.current?.click();`. Have you tried that way>

Comment: yes it didn't work.

Comment: @unknown_boundaries just catch up with you, my below answer helped you?

Comment: I ended up with -

if (e.detail <= 1) {
    // ignores double-click to prevent re-riggering
     uploadRef.current?.click();
   }

Comment: this did not work, still looking for a solution

Answer (score -1):

You can try to have `timeout` for that click event

```
let timer //initialise timer somewhere
const onClick = React.useCallback(
    () => {
        //remove the previous timer, once an user clicks again
        timer && clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
           uploadRef.current?.click();
        }, 200) // this is an idle time before opening file picker, it works for me, you can modify it as you wish
     },
    [timer])
```